# htaccess ErrorDocument with Subdomains

Tags: .htaccess, web

So I recently tried to make my own 404 page. It looks good, but after hours of searching how to add it (didn't work), I give up... How can I get the same `ErrorDocument` on every subdomain with this structure?

```
/var/www
  -main site
    -.htaccess
  -subdomain
    -.htaccess
  -error
    -error***.html (*** = which error, 404 etc)
    ...
```

I tried inheriting `.htaccess` in /var/www, but it gives me a error:

`Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.`

How can i do this? Every try either just gave me "/error/404.html" as html or encountered an error. The document root is in the Subdomains folder, that's the problem. And going back a directory in .htaccess doesn't work (../error).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems like it doesn't work. I've now just linked a error.php in every directory and there the htaccess links to them